# I want to click(or simulate) click to an image

Tags: c#, browser

First of all, I have done some search yet found no working way.
Anyway, web-site have this:

```
<td id="TOOL" width="30">
<img border="0" src="../../i/tool.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='../../i/tool/toola.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='../../images/tool/tool.jpg'" onclick="return Stuffx ();"/>
</td>
```

the important part here, is, I believe "return Stuffx();"

So I can click buttons by doing Invokemembers and raiseevents, but how do I click this image thing ?
Btw, Im trying to do this on "webbrowser" and c# if you havent noticed from tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute JavaScript functions using the HtmlDocument's InvokeScript method.

```
InvokeScript("Stuffx");
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [WatiN](http://watin.org/). Its cannot be easier. Below you have an example about how to open google and click om the "Google Search" button. If, instead of click on a button you want to click on an image, use browser.Image(...)

```
using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
{    
    browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();
}
```

Comment: This wasnt proper answer to my question yet thank you so much as well :) Wish I knew this WatiN earlier.